# Table in textwidth

Tags: tables

When I want to fit the table the textwidth, I use the following Code:

```
\begin{table}[t]  
                \small
                \caption{Summary descriptive statistics}
                \label{tab1:summary_by_affiliation}
                \centering{\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} c}
\toprule

\multicolumn{1}{c}{Test 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Test 2}  \\
\midrule
Mean & 6.37  \\
Median & 1.00  \\
Std. Dev. & 19.01  \\
Kurtosis & 39.33  \\
Skewness & 5.79  \\
Minimum & 0.09  \\
Maximum & 194.45  \\
Sum & 5845 \\
Count & 917  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}}

\vspace{-2ex}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\footnotesize
\singlespacing
\item\hspace{-2.5pt}\textit{Note}: Test
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

The result Looks as follows:

[image]

But what i actually want is this (without the vertical bars etc, but the allignmend should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: `\centering` is a switch and does not take an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may achieve your formatting objective by switching from a `tabular*` to a `tabularx` environment and employing a centered version of the `X` column type instead of a the `c` column type.

There would appear to be no need for a `tablenotes` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
%\small
\caption{Summary descriptive statistics}
\label{tab1:summary_by_affiliation}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CC}
\toprule
Test 1 & Test 2  \\
\midrule
Mean & 6.37  \\
Median & 1.00  \\
Std. Dev. & 19.01  \\
Kurtosis & 39.33  \\
Skewness & 5.79  \\
Minimum & 0.09  \\
Maximum & 194.45  \\
Sum & 5845 \\
Count & 917  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip 
\footnotesize
\textit{Note}: Test
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect.
Any idea how i Can fit the notes if I want my table to have a specific width? i.e. the notes should have the same width as the table.
For instance, in this example, I set the width to {.7\textwidth}, but the notes width do not match.

Comment: Load the `threeparttable` package and place the `\caption` statement, the `tabularx` env., and the notes in a threeparttable` environment.